# Regex that stop at a line

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to build a regex that stop when a line is equal to "--- admonition".

For example, I have :

```
??? ad-question Quels sont les deux types de bornages ?

Il y en a deux :

- Le bornage amiable.

- Le bornage judiciaire.

test

--- admonition
```

I can have the same capture format multiple time on a page.

I want to retrieve (in every match) in a first group :

> Quels sont les deux types de bornages ?

and in a second :

> Il y en a deux :
>
> - Le bornage amiable.
> - Le bornage judiciaire.
>
> test

I tried :

```
^\?{3} ad-question {1}(.+)\n*((?:\n(?:^[^#].{0,2}$|^[^#].{3}(?<!---).*))+)
```

or

```
^\?{3} ad-question {1}(.+)\n*((?:\n(?:^[^\n#].{0,2}$|^[^\n#](?<!----).*))+)
```

but it didn't stop at "\n--- admonition" and it took the new line between the two group.

Is someone can help me build this regex ?

ps : I must have a new line between the two group and between group 2 and "---- admonition". So these lines must be avoid in the groups.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\?{3} ad-question (.+)\n+((?:(?!---).*\n)*?)\n+---` https://regex101.com/r/ju22F7/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 2 capture groups without matching the newlines in between the groups, but there must be at least a whole empty line in between the groups:

```
^\?{3} ad-question (.+)\n{2,}((?:(?!---).*\n)*?)\n+---
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\?{3} ad-question`  Match `??? ad-question`
- `(.+)` Capture group 1, match the whole line
- `\n{2,}` Match 2 or more newlines, so that there is at least an empty line in between
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `(?:(?!---).*\n)*?` Repeat as least as possible matching all lines and the newline, that do not start with ---
- `)` Close group 2
- `\n+---` Match 1 or more newlines and `---`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/giQTwz/1)

If there should be at least a single newline present:

```
^\?{3} ad-question (.+)\n+((?:(?!---).*\n)*?)\n*---
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1yirb3/1)

Comment: `(?:(?!---).*\n)*?` since you use a negative lookahead to check all lines, you don't need the non-capturing group quantifier to be non-greedy, `(?:(?!---).*\n)*` will work too. Other way, but the pattern is longer, you can check only the first non-empty line with the lookahead and then use a non-greedy quantifier for the remaining lines: https://regex101.com/r/baaOXp/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see, I used the non greedy version to not overmatch in this case https://regex101.com/r/ERv4oe/1 But I think there are ways to account for that as well.

Comment: Yes, but with your pattern you don't need it: https://regex101.com/r/8LeZox/1

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
\?{3}\s*(.+)\s*((?:(?!-{3} admonition)[\s\S])*?)\s*-{3} admonition
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9pOSs4/4)**

---

**Explanation:**

- `\?{3}` - matches 3 occurrences of `?`
- `\s*` - matches 0 or more white-spaces
- `(.+)` - matches 1 or more occurrences of any character except a new line and captures it in group 1
- `\s*` - matches 0 or more white-spaces
- `((?:(?!-{3} admonition)[\s\S])*?)\s*-{3} admonition` - matches 0 or more occurrences of any character that does not start with `--- admonition`. After matching all such characters, it matches 0 or more whote-spaces followed by the word `--- admonition`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It works to detect the first occurrence but not occurrences after.

Comment: You are welcome :). But, it [works](https://regex101.com/r/9pOSs4/4) for multiple occurrences too

Answer (score 1):

You most probably need re.**DOTALL** and re.**MULTILINE** flags. You can also use it as *inline flag* within the pattern: `'(?s)' and '(?m)'`.

**DOTALL** lets `'.'` also capture `'\n'` which it normally does NOT match (re.DOTALL is python - other dialects have similar flags, f.e.:  [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) ).

You can capture yours with `r'\?\?\?(.*?)\?(.*?)--- admonition'` and those 2 flags.

Python example (JS has DOTALL

```
import re

text = """??? ad-question Quels sont les deux types de bornages ?

Il y en a deux :

- Le bornage amiable.

- Le bornage judiciaire.

test

--- admonition
??? ad-question 2  types de bornages ?

Il y en a deux :

- Le bornage judiciaire.

test 2

--- admonition"""


pattern = r'\?\?\?(.*?)\?(.*?)--- admonition'

for f in re.finditer(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
    print(f)
    print(f.groups())  # tuple of groups (A, B, ..) of grouped matches
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 144), match='??? ad-question Quels sont les deux types de born>
(' ad-question Quels sont les deux types de bornages ', 
 '\n\nIl y en a deux :\n\n- Le bornage amiable.\n\n- Le bornage judiciaire.\n\ntest\n\n')

<re.Match object; span=(145, 251), match='??? ad-question 2  types de bornages ?\n\nIl y en>
(' ad-question 2  types de bornages ', 
 '\n\nIl y en a deux :\n\n- Le bornage judiciaire.\n\ntest 2\n\n')
```

Pattern `'\?\?\?(.*?)\?(.*?)--- admonition'` explained:

```
\?\?\?                 - 3 literal question marks (QM)
(.*?)\?                - non greedy capture (including \n) up to 1st QM
(.*?)--- admonition    - non greedy capture up to ---admonition
```

Answer (score 1):

So many ways I guess in doing this; my two cents:

```
^\?{3}\h+ad-question\h+(.+)\n+((?:.*\n?)+?)\n+^---\h+admonition$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TZW4R1/1)

---

- `^\?{3}\h+ad-question\h+` - Start-line anchor followed by three literal question marks, 1+ (Greedy) horizontal whitespace characters and literally 'ad-question' and another 1+ whitespace chars;
- `(.+)` - Your 1st capture group with 1+ (Greedy) characters other than newline;
- `\n+` - 1+ (Greedy) newline-chars.
- `((?:.*\n?)+?)` - A 2nd capture group with a nested non-capture group matched 1+ (Lazy) times, capturing 0+ characters upto an optional newline char;
- `\n+` - 1+ (Greedy) newline-chars.
- `^---\h+admonition$` - From start-line anchor to end-line anchor, match: '---', multiple whitespace chars and 'admonition'.